# Push Notifications in windows 8 desktop app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

Hey i have been developing a windows 8 desktop app using XAML and C#. I have to implement push notification functionality in it. But i cannot keep my database on cloud due to some security reasons. Is there any other solution so that i can keep my database inside my network only but still can write mobile service to implement push notifications. Any link or suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically in push notification scenarios there are three pieces:

1. App.
2. Cloud Service.
3. Push Notification Service

Where the app registers for notifications, passes the registration to the cloud service which can then use the PNS to send notifications.

However the Cloud Service component doesn't need to be in "the cloud" it can be anywhere the client app can connect to and send the registration. It's just a web service hosted somewhere, be in a cloud platform, your own hosting etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is a company that provides this service for you for free called Notice Software. They provide push within apps at not cost and handle the cloud interaction etc. I think the product site is NativePush.com....also used UrbanAirship but not sure I want to pay that much! Frees always best :)